# Docker compose keywords

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, keyword

I am new to docker and try to understand docker compose working, when i read a .yml file i am little bit confused about yml keywords like:

```
version: "3"
services:
  myservice:
    build:
```

In above code `services` and `build` act like keywords docker knows what to do against these specific keywords but `myservice` is act like variable and could be any name of your desire.

Another snippet is:

```
version: "2"
services:
  postgres:
    connector: pg
    debug: true
    listenOn: tcp://0.0.0.0:5454
    credentials:
      host: localhost
      username:
        from: abc
        get: XYZ
      password:
        from: abc
        get: XYZ
```

This snippet is taken from one of an open source project .yml file

In this yml file i am unable to understand which words act like `keywords` or `variables` ?

Like i search `listenOn` on docker docs page but i did not found it. If it is not a keyword then how docker react to this word?

Specific question is; is there a cheat sheet of keywords (like python language keywords) for building docker containers?

Comment: Not sure what your exact doubt is, but the syntax is [documented](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#services-top-level-element). The tool just includes a parser that's aware of the features.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thanks for the guide but given link does not have `listenOn` keyword which is used in above .yml file.

Comment: As far as I can find out, the ListenOn keyword is from a product called `secretless`. The YAML file you're seeing isn't a docker compose file. It's a secretless file. They look very similar, but secretless supports some extra keywords (like listenOn) that aren't in docker compose.

Comment: https://github.com/cyberark/secretless-broker#performance (scroll down a little bit to find `secretless.yml`).

Comment: YAML is just [a file format](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html), sort of like JSON but with less required punctuation.  There aren't "keywords" _per se_ but tools that read YAML files know that they're looking for specific dictionary keys.

Comment: @DavidMaze You are right `tools that read YAML files know that they're looking for specific dictionary keys` my question is which dictionary keys are aware to docker tool while parsing YAML files. is there any cheat sheet available?